# Video is not playing in AVPlayer with

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` to play a video with the `localPath` URL but it is not playing on `AVPlayer`.

And i am getting `localPath` with this code:

```
var selectedAssets = [TLPHAsset]()

for abcd in self.selectedAssets {
        let asset = abcd

        if asset.type == .video {


          //------------- Video Path --------------------//
          let fm = FileManager.default
          let docsurl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
          let url = docsurl.appendingPathComponent(stringUrl!)

      }
 }
```

here is the path:-

`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/915BA33E-5DB9-42C4-B5CD-3898D81FBDC5/Documents/77666c29-75a3-4d89-aecf-15d0f47fbe83.mp4`

```
let video = dbImageDataModel[indexPath.row].fileUrl
print(video)
playerView = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: video))
playerViewController.player = playerView
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
      self.playerViewController.player!.play()
})
```

Comment: What does `URL(fileURLWithPath: video)` print?

Comment: @TheTiger actually I am getting local path of any video and storing in local database and getting from it. And after print getting this : `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/915BA33E-5DB9-42C4-B5CD-3898D81FBDC5/Documents/77666c29-75a3-4d89-aecf-15d0f47fbe83.mp4`

Comment: This is the print description of `print(video)` ... I'm asking what does it print `URL(fileURLWithPath: video)` here. print your url and share.

Comment: This is the `print(video)` result `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/915BA33E-5DB9-42C4-B5CD-3898D81FBDC5/Documents/77666c29-75a3-4d89-aecf-15d0f47fbe83.mp4`

Comment: what does @ stringUrl contains

Comment: I have updated all the things . please check

Comment: @Coding I'm asking what URL prints when you are passing it to player. So print it here `playerView = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: video))`. Share the print description of `URL(fileURLWithPath: video)` not `print(video)`. Because your string already contains `file://`.

Comment: @TheTiger yes you are right  with the `URL(fileURLWithPath: video)` it is again including `file://` but now I am using  `URL(String: video)` . Is this correct .

Comment: Yes correct......

Comment: @TheTiger But again it is not playing.

Comment: Does it `URL(fileURLWithPath: video)` print `nil` ? You haven't shared its printing description yet.

Comment: @TheTiger. `URL(fileURLWithPath: video)` result is `file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/64E562B8-19B6-4740-9BA6-8932249D35A6/Documents/77666c29-75a3-4d89-aecf-15d0f47fbe83.mp4 -- file:///`

Comment: @TheTiger Is there any way to do it ? I am stuck with it. And now I a using `URL(String: video)` instead of `URL(fileURLWithPath: video)` but again same issue not playing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196559/discussion-between-thetiger-and-coding).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong API.

`absoluteString` returns the URL string including the `file://` scheme. To create a new URL you have to use `URL(string` rather than `URL(fileURLWithPath`.

To clarify

- `absoluteString` returns `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application...`. To create an URL use `URL(string:`
- `path` returns `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application...`. To create an URL use `URL(fileURLWithPath:`

Comment: I am using `absoluteString ` just because I am storing the path with the `String` formate in Realm Database. And `Realm ` is not supporting `URL ` or `NSURL ` type property in the database.

Comment: Then use the proper API to create the URL as described in my answer. For a file system URL I'd prefer `.path` → `URL(fileURLWithPath`

Comment: I have changed my code according to you but it is not working . Not playing